# Stopping iframe javascript timers when iframe is out of view

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am working on a blog article that will have several `<iframe>` areas showing some HTML5/Javascript animations with [`requestAnimationFrame()` and/or `setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Timers). (I am using iframes because the blogging framework itself doesn't allow me to include any custom Javascript.)

These animations are somewhat compute-intensive, so I am wondering if there is any way to have the Javascript in the iframe detect when it is out of view, and pause execution until it re-enters view. Is there a way to do this?

(p.s. the site where I am hosting my iframe is a different domain  than the parent document, so I guess that makes this tougher/impossible due to same-origin policy issues.)

Answer (score 0):

Oh -- it looks like [IntersectionObserver](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/intersectionobserver) can help me here; [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) of the latest browsers appear to support this kind of thing that can call a callback function when a target element's "intersection ratio" crosses one or more thresholds. (and there is a [polyfill for other browsers](https://github.com/WICG/IntersectionObserver/tree/gh-pages/polyfill))

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  function observeForVisibility(target, thresholds, func)
  {
    var callback = function(entries, observer) { 
      for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; ++i)
      {
        if (entries[i].target == target)
        {
          func(target, entries[i].intersectionRatio);
        }
      }  
    }  
    var observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, 
       {threshold: thresholds});
    observer.observe(target);
  }

  var target = document.getElementById('some_id');
  observeForVisibility(target, [0], function(target, ratio)
    { console.log(target, ratio); }); 

});
```